# Rename files and append parent directory name to filenames?

Tags: bash, rename, macos

I am trying to rename files and append their parent directory name to them (and move them to a new folder named Photos).

I've been trying to do this with [rename](http://plasmasturm.org/code/rename/) and [mmv](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/mmv.1.html), but I am having difficulties doing this when standing inside directory A in the example below.

```
$ pwd
/A
$ tree
.
├── 1.jpg
├── 2.jpg
└── 3.jpg
```

But it works fine when running rename from one step higher up in the folder hierarchy.

```
$ pwd
/
$ tree
.
└── A
    ├── 1.jpg
    ├── 2.jpg
    └── 3.jpg

$ rename 's|(.*)/(.*)|$1/Photos/$1 - $2|' */*.jpg -p
$ tree
.
└── A
    └── Photos
        ├── A\ -\ 1.jpg
        ├── A\ -\ 2.jpg
        └── A\ -\ 3.jpg
```

How can this be accomplished when standing in directory 'A' in the example?

Answer (score 1):

OK that's a fancier `rename` than what I have, so first try using sed:

```
Dir=$(basename "$PWD")
mkdir -p Photos
ls *.jpg|sed 's|\(.*\)|mv "\1" "Photos/'"$Dir"' - \1"|'    |sh
```

which I guess translates to your rename like this:

```
Dir=$(basename "$PWD")
rename 's|(.*)|Photos/'"$Dir"' - $1|' *.jpg -p
```

Comment: Thanks for the classic method. I've never seen something piped to sh before. Could you elaborate a little how that sed command works with mv inside?

I also did som further experiments with the rename command. I write in a separate post for readability.

Comment: Using the sed route, I should warn that you probably want to be sure that some attacker can't get to your filenames and do _bad things_ since  the filenames go into shell commands! Anyway, the sed is just taking the filename and putting each into it's own `mv`  command. For testing you can leave out the `|cat` to see what commands are generated, then add it once you are happy with what you see.

Answer (score 0):

Expanding upon [AndreBeaud's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/718091/97255).  I also did some further experiments with the `rename` command. These four variants all work, it can probably be done even cleaner. I noticed that AndreBeaud didn't use `eval`, instead used single quotes to concatenate the strings. Handy.

1. Short but kind of difficult to read.

   ```
   rename 's|.*/(.*)/(.*)|Photos/$1 - $2|' `pwd`/*.jpg --make-dirs
   ```
2. Easier to read with the folder name in the substitute part.

   ```
   eval "rename 's|(.*)|Photos/$(basename `"pwd"`) - \$1|' *.jpg --make-dirs"
   ```
3. Create variable first. Not critical in this case, since it's only used once. Easy to follow.

   ```
   Dir=$(basename `"pwd"`); eval "rename 's|(.*)|Photos/$Dir - \$1|' *.jpg --make-dirs"
   ```
4. Variable first, but with the folder name in the find part, messy.

   ```
   Dir=$(basename `"pwd"`); rename 's|.*/(.*)/(.*)|Photos/$1 - $2|' ../$Dir/*.jpg --make-dirs
   ```

Combining both AndreBeaud's and my versions can make this short version:

```
rename 's|(.*)|Photos/'"$(basename "$PWD")"' - $1|' *.jpg --make-dirs
```